# Spring @Transactional in H2 for insert statement

Tags: java, sql, spring, h2, transactional

I want to insert data in my table, but insert only that doesn't exist in my DB. I'm using Spring 5, jdbcTemplate and in-memory H2.

I need something like that below, but H2 doesn't have PL.
How can I write a right java method with `@Transactional` annotation to reach atomic operation. Something very like `putIfAbsent()` in `ConcurrentHashMap`.

What I need if H2 has PL:

```
    @Transactional
    public void create(String city, Double temperature) {
    String query = "BEGIN\n" +
            "   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM weather \n" +
            "                   WHERE city = :city)\n" +
            "   BEGIN\n" +
            "       INSERT INTO weather (city, temperature, time_stamp)\n" +
            "       VALUES (:city, :temperature, :time_stamp)\n" +
            "   END\n" +
            "END"; 
MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramMap.addValue("city", city);
    paramMap.addValue("temperature", temperature);
    paramMap.addValue("time_stamp", new Date());
    jdbcTemplate.update(query, paramMap);
    System.out.println("Inserted into Weather Table Successfully");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for silly question - what is PL ?

Comment: How about splitting the script in two requests: get and insert AND inscreasing isolation? It will prevent other transaction from commiting an identical item &  your db-script won't be platform-dependent

Comment: Procedure language

Comment: Why don't you use [merge](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge) instead?

Comment: resolved with creating unique constraint on column in database